# Embed a form onto a tabcontrol in windows forms

Tags: c#, forms, tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer

I have a tab control in a windows form and I want to be able to click on a tab and in the body area of the tab I want it to display another form as an embedded component.  Is this possible? If so, can someone please provide an example or a link to an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you move *other* form contents to user control and embed user control instead?

Comment: How hard do you think it would be to move 43 forms to user controls? or rather how easy would it be to move forms to user controls?

Comment: Anything ranging from *trivial* to *impossible* depending on how much your forms are only forms, or forms with domain logic mixed here and there :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Tabbed MDI Child Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TabbedMDIChildForms.aspx)

Comment: Do you know of any other examples?  That one doesn't explain how everything works very well.

Comment: This is the actual correct answer, that link shows everything how to make it work. I tested it and it works like a charm.

Comment: Just don't forget to set the **height** of the tab control to 24 px

Answer (score 7):

You can embed a Form but it's not the best choice.

Better place the contents on UserControls and add that to the TabPage.

Answer (score 6):

Set your MainForm (Parent) as  IsMDIContainer = true;

Create an instance of the ChildForm and call this function:

```
FormChild frmChild = new FormChild();
AddNewTab(frmChild);
```

Copy this Function to your code:

```
private void AddNewTab(Form frm)
{

    TabPage tab = new TabPage(frm.Text);

    frm.TopLevel = false;

    frm.Parent = tab;

    frm.Visible = true;

    tabControl.TabPages.Add(tab);

    frm.Location = new Point((tab.Width - frm.Width) / 2, (tab.Height - frm.Height) / 2);

    tabControl.SelectedTab = tab;

}
```

Comment: I removed frm.Location and added WindowState = Maximized and FormBorderStyle = None. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

I think the other answer has the right idea; Tabbed MDI is probably what you want.

There is an approach where you create a UserControl that has the same content as the form and use that on the TabPage.

```
TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(sometext);
myUserControl = new myUserControlType();
myUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
myTabPage.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
myTabControl.Add(myTabPage);
```

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/270457-can-i-add-form-tabpage goes into more detail; but I'd look at the MDI stuff first.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use MDI, you can try to put everything from desired form to user control and add this user control in both form and tab.