# Attach a TabControl to MDI parent form instead of toolstrip

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a set of well-behaved Windows Forms that are embedded in DLL's that I do not have full control over.  These are part of a separate legacy projects that I'm trying to unify under one interface so that the application doesn't quite feel like popup hell.

I think the way to do this is to create an MDI parent form, and open the other forms as children of that.  One child form at a time as they're needed.  As they navigate one MDI document will close, and another will open.

The parent MDI form though, needs navigation controls.  And I'd like to use a tabcontrol.  Is it possible to attach a tabcontrol to the parent MDI form?  All I can find documentation for and examples of are toolstrips, but that's far too limiting for what I want to accomplish.

No code to show, sorry.  I'm not sure if what I want is possible at all.

**Update** As indicated below, I really didn't need MDI to accomplish what I set out to do.  Leaving the question as-is, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've read this correctly, then I don't think MDI is what you are looking for, since you want to use a TabControl to navigate to each form.

If you turn `TopLevel` to false and remove the border from a Form, you essentially turn the form into a UserControl, and can add it to the TabPage panel of your choosing:

```
  Form f = new Form();
  f.TopLevel = false;
  f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  tabPage1.Controls.Add(f);
  f.Visible = true;
```

Change `Form` to a form you are referencing from your DLL.

Comment: You're right, I think I overcomplicated this by dragging MDI through it all.  This will possibly work and I'll mark the answer as soon as I verify.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how this can work.  According to TabControl, only TabPages can be added, not forms.  Other SO pages respond to use MDI.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796334/embed-a-form-onto-a-tabcontrol-in-windows-forms?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @erict The form is being added to the *Controls* collection of the TabPage.